# Pyscript color input - triggers to soon

Tags: color-picker, pyscript

I'm using this html to have the user choose a color:

`<input type="color" id="main-color" name="head" value="#15347d"">`

Then I'm using a button to call my python function

`button py-click="generate_color_schemes(False)" id="button-submit">Update!</button>`

Works well. (`generate_color_schemes()` examines the `Element("main-color").value` to get the hex color.)

But I'd like to combine the two, so clicking on the input - opens a picker and fires the python function as the user clicks inside the color picker as well as when they leave.

But (as expected) adding `py-click` fires my function when the input is first clicked and not when the color chooser popup closes or as the user clicks inside the color picker.

I think I want pyclick to be triggering on the `oninput` event as well as the `onchange` event.

Is there a way to combine the `input type='color'` with `py-click` to get this behaviour ?

Comment: I.e. this doesn't fire on close or interactively. ```<input type="color" id="main-color" name="head" value="#15347d" py-click="generate_color_schemes(False)">```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you say, you've got the right syntax but the wrong event(s). Rather than listening for the `click` event, you can listen to the [input event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/input_event) (which is dispatched every time the value of an input changes) or the [change event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/change_event) (which is dispatched, in this case, when the color picker closes). To do this in PyScript (or to listen to any event), the HTML attribute is `py-[event]` where `[event]` is the type of the event. In this case, you'll use the `py-input` and `py-change` attributes.

Here's a working example in the current release of PyScript (2023.03.1), which I mention in case the events API changes in the future. The MDN docs have [a longer example](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/color#example) in JavaScript.

```html
<!-- Written for PyScript 2023.03.1 -->
<input type="color" id="main-color" py-input="do_something_with_color()" py-change="do_something_else()">

<py-script>
    import js
    def do_something_with_color():
        elem = js.document.getElementById("main-color")
        value = elem.value
        print(f'Chosen color: {value}') # do something here

    def do_something_else():
        elem = js.document.getElementById("main-color")
        value = elem.value
        print(f'The final color chosen was: {value}') # do something here
</py-script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could also `prompt()` the user for `input()`...

```py
import contextlib

with contextlib.suppress(ImportError):
    from pyscript import window
    input = window.prompt

main_color = input('Please enter the main color.')
```